# Passport bcrypt password is different than password from db

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

In my `local-register` I store my user data in the database. To hash the password I use bcrypt:

```
console.log(password);
password = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
console.log(password);
```

If I sign up a user with the password `stackoverflow` the password looks like this:

```
stackoverflow 
$2a$10$uoJH1Wo9b7SQploRptfODe1Q2kRC3skQoUNOIhAmHg2AWykWQwGvW
```

When I log in a user `stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com` with the password `stackoverflow`

```
var hashedpassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
console.log(password);
console.log(hashedpassword);

stackoverflow
$2a$10$aq869JEMWBQ8vCfXfuRvlOPdUvq.UhTz4Ge.kB3n7wSyvhjBsm8r2
```

So even though I use the same bcrypt module the hash is different every time I log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the inner workings of bcrypt, but the hash may look different for the same string each time because the salt is generated as part of the hashing. Thus, you can't do:

```
stored = hash(old);
guess = hash(guess);
valid = stored == guess;
```

Instead you have to use the `compare` method, as in:

```
/* password is *not* hashed! */
bcrypt.compare(password, usersHashedPassword, cb);
```

Comment: What's the cb for? callback? I'm getting an error the `cb`is undefined.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma yes -- you can also use `.compareSync`

Comment: Alright looks like, I ended up wrapping it in a wrapper. `if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, current.password)){
                        console.log('true')
                    } else {
                        console.log('false')
                        return done(null, false);
                    }`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma effectively you can do `bcrypt.compare(password, current.password, done)`